# GameRanger issue on linux mint

Tags: linux

I would like to play AOM on gameranger on my linux mint 17.3 rosa. 
I can play AOM with wine but i cant open gameranger. everytime I try this error pops up:

gameranger has encountered an unexpected error and must quit.
this error has been logged automatically.

this should be the log:

p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: impossibile aprire il file oggetto condiviso: File o directory non esistente
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:systray:wine_notify_icon unhandled tray message: 4
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x41be570, overlapped 0x3ff4f54): stub
fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (0x41be670 0x00000ff0 0x41be6b8) Stub!
[0512/164500:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(143)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
wine: Call from 0x7b83aace to unimplemented function dnsapi.dll.DnsFlushResolverCacheEntry_A, aborting

I've wandered around the internet, trying this trying that. Nothing works.

Answer (score -2):

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20206

here is the solution, look down the page.